# How can I demonstrate this in SPICE model?

Tags: ltspice

The active filter below is supposed to filter signal noise, but I also want to make the simulation where one can see 50/60Hz common mode inference will not be rejected.

[image]

How can this circuit be modified so that this circuit is almost useless for removing common mode interference?

Comment: What do you think "common mode noise" refers to with a single-ended input? If you put noise on both "ground" and input and measure relative to that new reference it won't be 'almost'  useless, it will be exactly useless.

Comment: Yes I wanted to simulate and show that in SPICE. If I apply a 50Hz source at the bottom of the Vin the filter will filter it, So my question is about how to add source which represents the 50Hz common mode interference effect in reality. I hope I made it more clear what I mean(?)

Comment: Are you asking how to add common mode noise to the circuit?

Comment: Yes. I was wondering if the cut-off were 10Hz would 50Hz still appear same amount at the output or a differential amplifier is a must. How to demonstrate if so, thst this circuit will not help 50Hz CM issue even if the filter cut off is 10Hz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean something like this:

[image]

You'll notice that I've added C2 to make it a proper Sallen-Key filter. Otherwise it won't do anything useful (all positive DC feedback).

I've also added a 5V bias to the input voltage since you have no negative supply.

The common-mode voltage is V3, which I've made 10mV at 60Hz.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If the cut-off were 10Hz would 50Hz still appear same amount at the output?

Comment: Yes, even if the output was shorted to Vss.

Comment: I wanted to be sure about it. Thanks! The only solution is using a differential or InAmp right?

Comment: Using a differential input may help depending on exactly what is going on.