# Simulating CM interference for an inAmp

Tags: operational-amplifier

Which one of the following is correct to simulate CM interference for [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8221.pdf) inAmp?

[image]

Reference is grounded in my case since I don't need offset. But I'm confused which way we need to inject the common mode in simulation.

(Figure2 does not reject anything in simulation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Which one of the following is correct to simulate CM interference for
> this InAmp?*

If the input common mode rejection for the InAmp were perfect then, in circuit 2, the modulation of the REF input by the common-mode signal would result in the common-mode signal totally appearing at the output terminal hence, circuit 2 does not measure the InAmp's CMRR. Circuit 1 does measure CMRR because, it ties REF to 0 volts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A while ago I asked a similar question where a single ended amplifier is used: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/645463/how-can-i-demonstrate-this-in-spice-model And from the answer, I wanted to develop a method to simulate CM interference for such circuits. In that answer "all" the grounds including supply ground are star connected and the a CM is injected from that point. If I do the same thing here I obtain Figure2. For simulating CM voltage should we only inject from the common ground of the inputs section?

Comment: REF is part of the output stage and isn't generally regarded as an input subject to any form of CMRR. The reason is simple; it's a single ended input and, because of this, it cannot do anything other than add/subtract the voltage it receives at its pin to/from the output @pnatk

Comment: "it's a single ended input" do you refer to the other circuit in the link?

Comment: REF is a single-ended input

Comment: I think "REF is part of the output stage and isn't generally regarded as an input subject to any form of CMRR." explains what I should do. Thanks a lot!